# Change octave executable to jupyter kernel in emacs octave-mode

Tags: emacs, jupyter-console

How do I change the `octave-mode` to use the command `jupyter kernel --kernel octave` as the default octave shell?

Edit: Here's a list of things I tried (adding them here as suggested in the comments):

1. Changed the variable `inferior-octave-program` using:

```
(eval-after-load 'octave (setq inferior-octave-program "jupyter console --kernel octave"))
```

This however gives the error: `Searching for program: No such file or directory, jupyter console --kernel octave`. And yes, I do have jupyter and octave_kernel installed and can launch it from terminal with `jupyter console --kernel octave`.

Answer (score 0):

Untested - customize the variable `inferior-octave-program`; or if you prefer to do things manually, add the following to your emacs init file:

```el
(eval-after-load 'octave (setq inferior-octave-program "jupyter kernel --kernel octave"))
```

The doc string for `inferior-octave-program` says:

> inferior-octave-program is a variable defined in ‘octave.el’.
> Its value is "octave"
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation:
> Program invoked by ‘inferior-octave’.

Comment: This was indeed one of the first things i tried and it doesn't work. It gives me a `Searching for program: No such file or directory, jupyter console --kernel octave` error. And yes, I do have jupyter and octave_kernel installed and can launch it from terminal with `jupyter console --kernel octave`.

Comment: That's probably (still an untested guess ;-) ) because it tries to exec the string. Try putting the command in a script (say `/usr/local/bin/joctave`), make it executable and then assign that to `inferior-octave-program`.

Comment: BTW, you should have mentioned that you had tried that in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question. I tried creating a local script, but now it just makes Emacs hang until I hit `ctrl-g` without ever launching an inferior octave buffer!